# How to get npm lite server serve full content of my webpage?

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-scripts, html5boilerplate

I installed *html5-boilerplate* and the *lite-server* modules using `npm install html5-boilerplate --save-dev` and `npm install lite-server --save-dev` respectively.

I had to copy `index.html` from the `node_modules` folder in order to serve up the content using `npm start`. All I see is the `<p>` tag being rendered as shown in this image.

[image: this image]

This is how my working directory looks like.

```
Directory of D:\Full_Stack_Web_Development

27-02-2019  09:58    <DIR>          .
27-02-2019  09:58    <DIR>          ..
27-02-2019  10:05             1,871 index.html
27-02-2019  09:55    <DIR>          node_modules
27-02-2019  09:55           125,319 package-lock.json
27-02-2019  09:57               739 package.json
               3 File(s)        127,929 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  213,613,010,944 bytes free

D:\Full_Stack_Web_Development>
```

and this is how my `package.json` file looks like. `index.html` can be viewed [here](https://github.com/alokananda-y/Full_Stack_Web_Development/blob/master/index.html)

```
{
  "name": "full_stack_web_development",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "beginning front end development using html5 boilerplate",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/alokananda-y/Full_Stack_Web_Development.git"
  },
  "author": "alokananda y",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/alokananda-y/Full_Stack_Web_Development/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/alokananda-y/Full_Stack_Web_Development#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html5-boilerplate": "^7.0.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H5BP is pretty flexible, so there are a few ways to do what you want to do.  You can:

1. Copy the entire contents of `node_modules/html5-boilerplate`up to the root level of your folder, not just the index.html. The basic folder structure you're aiming for is what we have in our [dist](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/tree/master/dist) folder.
2. You can change all of the links in the index.html to point to the h5bp resources in `node_modules/html5-boilerplate`So, instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">` you would do `<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css">`
3. The easiest is actually to download the latest [version](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/releases/download/v7.0.1/html5-boilerplate_v7.0.1.zip), unzip the folder and then run `npm install --save-dev lite-server`inside that folder. That way the only dependency would be lite-server and h5bp would be ready to go. This is what I would do. We offer the project via npm but it's not really a *dependency* in the way that other packages are it's the starting point for a whole site or application.